# How to get this onfido cordova plugin to initialise properly?

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

Im trying to get this onfido cordova plugin to work but even though I get no errors it doesnt seem to do anything.

https://github.com/rewireltd1/cordova-plugin-onfido

This is a simple Ionic tutorial app which ive added a button to, which calls a method in my ts file to initialize the plugin.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector: 'page-hello-ionic',
templateUrl: 'hello-ionic.html'
}) 

export class HelloIonicPage {
applicantId: string = APPLICANT_ID
token: string = TOKEN
options: any;
constructor(

) {
this.options = {
  token:  this.token, // IMPORTANT: see notes
  applicant_id: this.applicantId,
  flow_steps: [ 'welcome', 'document', 'face', 'final'],
}
}

handleOnfido() {

try {
  console.log(1)
  window['cordova'].plugins.onfido.init((res) => {
    console.log(res)
    this.onComplete(res)
  }, this.options)
  console.log(2)

} catch (error) {
  console.log('ERROR', error)
}




}
onComplete(completeResponse) {
console.log('in on complete', completeResponse)
}
}
```

The app successfully builds on my android and when I click the button I get the logs 1 and 2 so no errors but then nothing. From looking at the Github does it look like im doing anything wrong? Any assistance would be massively helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Your `catch` will not receive errors thrown by `init` but it sure looks like it is trying to.

Comment: I tried to put a catch on the init after this.options) put it said that it didnt return a promise so I tried wrapping the whole block in a try catch...

Comment: That will not work. Look into promisifying it or pass an error hander.

Comment: @user10045300 did you manage to open the onfido sdk with the plugin?

Comment: @MichaelGoldenberg No. Instead I build my own front end and integrated with their api in the end and its had pretty good results.